# Kendo UI Grid virtual scrolling makes infinite ajax hits

Tags: ajax, kendo-grid, lazy-loading

I am loading a Kendo UI grid with virtual scrolling option on and for un-identified reasons when I scroll down when inside the grid infinite hits are made to the get grid data method.

My page also has angular JS.

The page number is always sent as one, but it should at least be incremented to two.

**Grid has been defined as following:**

```
dataSource: {
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    transport: {
        read: URL
    },
    schema: {
        data: function(data) {
            /* Few business filter operation done here */
            return data.Items;
        },
        total: function(data) {
            if (data.Items != null && data.Items.length > 0) {
            // Every record of the current data set has total employees count
            // Thus returning the first value                                        
            return data.Items[0].totalEmployees;
        }
        return 0;
        },
                    scrollable: {
                        virtual: true
                    },
                sortable: true,
                columns: columns,
                dataBound: function(arg) {
                    /* few more business operations */
                },
                scrollable: {
                    virtual: true
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                editable: {
                    'mode': 'inline',
                    'createAt': 'top'
                },
```

**Image showing infinite hits:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was loading the kendo.all.js file more than once, precisely thrice. I made sure it only loads once and the issue is gone.